# How to use chrome with Windows authentication?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, single-sign-on

I am trying to perform HTTP get & put operations on a intranet URL which is authenticated using Microsoft active directory domain accounts. This is working fine with IE but not using chrome. My chrome version is 49.0.2623.108.

Accessing the URL throws up a dialog for username and password and upon filling details, it fails with ERR_INVALID_HANDLE. Following are the things that I tried and failed(Please excuse for the lack of brevity):

1. I tried adding the URL and the Active directory server to Local intranet zones but still chrome returns the same error.
2. This link https://serverfault.com/questions/19914/google-chrome-passthrough-windows-authentication says we need to use authserverwhitelist for chrome. It is not working. Apparently, this feature of setting parameters has been moved from commandline to policy settings as per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=472145
3. I tried using policy settings like using chrome policy template. I imported the policy template on local computer policies\Administrative templates in gpedit.msc and set the parameters AuthServerWhitelist and AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist. I restarted the machine as well. It didnt help. Chrome still throws the same error.
4. I tried setting AuthserverWhitelist and AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist parameters on registry as well under path: HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome.

Is there a way to get this working on google chrome(version 49.0.2623.108)?

PS: Also after development, I am looking to package these web pages into a chrome app. Would chrome allow usage of windows active directory authentication in its app environment? Is there any way to fix it?